# Build a UIImage with multiple stretchable images

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, drawing, core-graphics

I have 3 images, a left cap, right cap, and center. Perhaps using `CGImageRefs` (?), is there a way to build a bitmap based on a `CGRect` that would center the center piece in some container, stretch the left cap until it reaches the center piece and the same for the right then produce a `UIImage`?

Comment: why don't you use one image instead?

Comment: The center piece has an arrow that can't be stretch. The final image is a map annotation callout that needs a stretchable width

Comment: did u try to use [`resizableImageWithCapInsets:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW50)

Comment: What @Pfitz Meant was that you can get this functionality from one image, you don't need to split it.

Comment: @borrrden i think he knows that. But the content in the middle will be stretched with the "normal" approach and he does not want this.

Comment: ^ Exactly. I'm playing around with Gabriele's solution right now to see if it works the way I think it does

Comment: @chris i think i have some code in a book about this. But the book is not here at the moment. I will look it up later if this is stil open

Comment: @Chris one thing bothers me though: since you do not stretch the caps nor the inner image what you do want to do be flexible? an extra part between the the caps and the arrow image?

Comment: @Pfitz that would be great if you can find that later. The cap images  kind of look like this: (_|   |center|   |_) There's a couple pixels that are straight that I want to stretch until it intersects with the center piece

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I looked it up as promised. Here is a solution:

#### The Basic Idea

- take the left cap and make an `UIImage` with stretched right side
- "glue" it with the arrow `UIImage`
- and now glue it with right cap with a left stretched side

And here is a small graphic how i think it could word

```
  ______ ........    ________      .........___________
 {______|........|  | arrow  |    |.........|__________)
left cap|lc flex     --------      rc flex  | right cap
```

#### The code

```
// get the images from disk
UIImage *leftCap = [UIImage imageNamed:@"leftCap.png"];
UIImage *arrow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
UIImage *rightCap = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rightCap"];

// stretch left and right cap
// calculate the edge insets beforehand !

UIImage *leftCapStretched = [leftCap resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset, leftInset, bottomInset, rightInset)];
UIImage *rightCapStretched = [rightCap resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset, leftInset, bottomInset, rightInset)];

CGFloat widthOfAllImages = leftCapStretched.size.width + arrow.size.width + rightCapStretched.size.width;

// build the actual glued image

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(widthOfAllImages, arrow.size.height), NO, 0);
[leftCapStretched drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[arrow drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(leftCap.size.width, 0)];
[rightCapStretched drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(leftCap.size.width + arrow.size.width, 0)];
UIImage* im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// now you should have a ready to use UIImage ;)
```

#### The alternative

Inspired by Jonathan Plaketts answers the same should ne possible with just `UIImageViews` and   stretching the UIImages as above.

Comment: There we go! Man, thank you so much! I've been trying a million different variations of solutions all day.

Comment: It seems it doesn't solve the main problem:
how will the program stretch this image if you set concrete width/height values? If you want to say that I can change the hardcoded values then why should I use automatic stretching if I still must define concrete size areas after the stretching?

Answer (score 1):

I say just do it programatically, yes it might waste a few CPU cycles but it'll be more fun.

OK, here we go...

Let's have 3 UIImageViews defined in the header

```
UIImageView *left;
UIImageView *center;
UIImageView *right;
```

In viewDidLoad we'll create them

```
left = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left.jpg"]];
center = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"center.jpg"]];
right = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right.jpg"]];


[self.view addSubview:left];
[self.view addSubview:center];
[self.view addSubview:right];

//set the position of the center piece wherever you like, whatever size is right for your arrow
[self setCenterFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)]; //we'll make this function below
```

then let's make a method you can use to set the position of the center image, and have the other images shimmy around into place, stretching themselves to the edges left and right.

```
-(void)setCenterFrame:(CGRect)rect
{
    center.frame = rect; // this is your arrow

    //set size of left
    left.frame = CGRectMake(0,rect.origin.y, rect.origin.x, rect.size.height);

    //work out how much space there is to the right
    float sizeToTheRight = (self.view.bounds.size.width - rect.size.width) - rect.origin.x ;

    //set size of right
    right.frame = CGRectMake(rect.size.width + rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y, sizeToTheRight, rect.size.height);


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your is a strange approach :)

You have three different images that compose a single stretchable image but you want to build it programmatically every time you have to use it in a certain way. This waste cpu cycles.
iOS framework allow you to stretch an image as you would. Open your files into your image editor (Photoshop, or something similar). Compose a single image containing the center image surrounded by the left and right cap.

Now you can use this image as every other images or you can stretch it as you would using the UIImage method

```
- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets
```

The UIEdgeInsets is a simple struct that identify your cap limits. So supposing you have to stretch 15pt left and 20pt right you insets will be:
top: 0
buttom:0
left:15
right:20

That's it.

[Here](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/08/stretchable-images-and-buttons/) for details. The article talk about a deprecated method from iOS 5.0 and above but the theory behind is the same.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the center part of the image will be stretched. If you read the comments below the question he clearly states that the center image is a arrow. I do not think he want it to be stretched ;)

Comment: Just finished trying this with no success. Unless there's a way to repeat two sections of pixels in the middle of an image like this without affecting the center

Comment: The clean way to do this so could be have an arrow image separated. Stretch the stretchable image as described before and than compose a new image using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions compose the two images into the context using drawAtPoint: UIImage method, grab the new image from context using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext and than close the graphic context using UIGraphicsEndImageContext.

Comment: I think this answer is totally useless. Read the question closely